# Check data frame(panda as pd) column value between two file then summation the value if match

Tags: python, pandas, match

I have made two data frame

```
df1=pd.read_csv()
df2=pd.read_csv()
```

df1

```
**A     B   C**

  Jhon  3   4

  David 3   6
```

df2

```
**A     B   C**

  leu   3   4

  Jhon  7   6
  David 6   8
```

I want to do like, if the name column(A) of df1 is match with name column(A) of df2, then the matched row of df2 will provide summation of total number of column B of df2.
finally my result will be like :

```
total_matchedValueOf_B= 7+6=13.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method and boolean indexing:

```py
df2.loc[df2['A'].isin(df1['A']), 'B'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [1642]: result = df1.merge(df2, on='A')['B_y'].sum()

In [1643]: result
Out[1643]: 13
```